# how to compare two doubles to the nearest hundredth digit in java

Tags: java, compare, double

I tried to multiply each of the double by 100 and then use Math. around() before doing Math.abs() < 0.00000001 but it doesn't work.

```
double A = Math.sqrt(3);  
double B = Math.sqrt(5);  
Boolean result = Math.abs(Math.round(A * 100.0)/100.0 - Math.round(B * 100.0)/100.0) < 0.00000001
```

Comment: Thank you for indicating that. I changed it to `Boolean result = Math.abs(Math.round( A * 100)/100 - Math.round( B * 100)/100) < 0.0000001` but it still doesn't work

Comment: @JonnyHenly you are wrong.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do.  If you're trying to round to the nearest 0.01, then multiplying by 100 is the right way to start (the other commenter is just wrong).  So if you have the values 3.143 and 3.142, multiplying by 100 and rounding gives you 314 for both.  But then why are you comparing the result to 0.00000001?  The result of the `-` and `Math.abs` is always going to be an integer, so this comparison doesn't make sense.  Maybe you want to divide the result by 100 after rounding, which would give you 3.14.  But comparing to 0.000000001 still doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I 'm actually comparing two doubles. I updated my code to `Boolean result = Math.abs(Math.round( A * 100)/100 - Math.round( B * 100)/100) < 0.0000001` but it still doesn't work. Our professor said when we are comparing two doubles, we need to use Math.abs(double A - double  B) < Epsilon so that's why I am using 0.000000001.

Comment: Sorry, you were originally right with hundredth. I was confused by your use of `Math.sqr()`, I thought you were squaring the numbers. The correct syntax is `Math.sqrt()`.

Comment: Well, yeah, but when you round them it doesn't make a whole lot of sense.    Your professor's advice is meant for other situations when you don't round.

Comment: Anyway, now you need to tell us what you mean by "it doesn't work".  What result are you expecting, and why?

Comment: Typically, this kind of error measurement check (if an error is less than epsilon - a small number) need not have the values rounded. You simply need to check if the absolute error is greater than certain number. In your case, it is rather confusing because the argument is `3` and `5`. Typically, we deal with very close number which requires double precision. For example: 0.123456789999 and 0.123456779999

Comment: I'm doing this for my homework and it's the case that I need to put the boolean result into a if statement for checking a condition of a boolean method. My method didn't pass the test case so i said "it doesn't work". In test cases, it uses a = 2 and b = 3. I don't know why the test case uses integer but the homework instruction says that we need to compare two doubles.

Comment: The problem with "doesn't work" as a problem report is that it gives no indication of what you expect. I tried your sample code and got `false`, which is exactly what you should get for that comparison.

Comment: I'm not trying to compare just these two value but actually two doubles. They can be any doubles. Sorry for the confusion, I just want to use Math.sqrt(3) and Math.sqrt(5) as examples. I just don't know how to compare two doubles to hundredth digit.

Comment: Please post a complete example that shows a program not behaving as you think it should.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for how to post an example.  Currently, we have no information on why things aren't working; we only have a little bit of code that isn't even the test case that's causing you the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Math.sqrt(3) rounded to two digits is 1.73, Math.sqrt(5) rounded to two digits is 2.24. How do you expect these two values to match?

Comment: I'm not trying to compare just these two value but actually two doubles. They can be any doubles. Sorry for the confusion, I just want to use Math.sqrt(3) and Math.sqrt(5) as examples. I just don't know how to compare two doubles to hundredth digit.